# How to style children element on hover parent avoiding nesting

Tags: html, css

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p class="child">TEST</p>
</div>
```

I would like to style `class="child"`when I am hovering `parent div`. I would like to avoid nesting

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by nesting but here are two ways to do it.

With CSS:

```
.parent:hover .child {
    // your styles
}
```

With JS:

```
document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('.child').classList.add('style-class-name');
})

document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
    document.querySelector('.child').classList.remove('style-class-name');
})
```